# Output audio stream in HTML template, django

Tags: django, audio

My python script uses pyaudio to output live audio after applying some filters. Now, I am adding the script to a website with django. The goal is to make a GUI with the audio stream and filters.

So far, I've only found `<audio controls></audio>` but this will only output a file, statically. This does not work for my needs. Is there a way I can output my pyaudio stream on my webpage?

How can I output my audio feed dynamically?

Edit:
Currently my feed is being fed as an array, x, which I am writing with stream.write(x) from pyaudio.

Comment: You want to return a downloaded file? Try to give more information of the way you want to manage the output audio file.

Comment: I added more info about the audio data. file-->transformation-->output(array)